# Strategy To Solve Diophantine Equations

Tags: diophantine-equations

Find all integers n for which the equation $$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=n$$ is solvable in positive integers.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: first strategy is to factorise both sides.LHS is $(x + y + z) (x^2 + y^2 + z^2-xy-yz-zx)$. For RHS if $n$ is prime then it's the simplest case as one of the factors on LHS would be one . And in case n is productc of two pimes then also wecan say one of factors on LHS is equalto one of those primes. Things get more complicated as nos of factors in $n$ increases.

Comment: Try factorising the LHS.